# Segmentation fault in finding factorial

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Why am I getting a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) with this program.

I am trying to find the factorial of a big number like 100, 200 but i don't know why in some cases it shows segmentation fault. Help me.

Constraints:

> - 1 ≤ T ≤ 100000
> - 1 ≤ N ≤ 100000

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long long int t,mod=1589540031;
    long long int a[5000]; 
    long long int n,i,j,temp,k,x;

    scanf("%lld",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
       scanf("%lld",&n);
       a[0]=1;  
       k=1;    

       temp = 0; 
       for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       {
            for(j=0;j<k;j++)
            {
               x = a[j]*i+temp; 
               a[j]=x%10; 
               temp = x/10; 
            }
             while(temp>0)
             { 
               a[k]=temp%10;
               temp = temp/10;
               k++; 
             }
      }
      for(i=k-1;i>=0;i--) 
          printf("%lld",a[i]%mod);
          printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For which input exactly you get the segfault ? That information should be part of the question.

Comment: Can you indent your code properly please ?

Comment: You don't link to the original assignment, but it looks as if you were supposed to calculate _n!_ modulo _m_. If so, you don't need to do the multiplication with an array. Just use [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) throughout. (Taking the remainder when printing out digits that are between 0 and 9 is pointless.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` array can contain 5000 elements, but you don't check if `k` and `j` are larger than 5000.

As soon as you try to access an element of the `a` array with an index > 5000 you get undefined behaviour.

```
for(j=0;j<k;j++)
{
  x = a[j]*i+temp;  // <<<<< j could be > 5000
  a[j]=x%10; 
  temp = x/10; 
}

while(temp>0)
{ 
  a[k]=temp%10;     // <<<<< k could be > 5000
  temp = temp/10;
  k++; 
}
...
```

Comment: The number 100000! has far more than 5000 digits - nearly 10 times. I notice you are applying the modulus on each array digit. That's quite wrong. You are probably  (this smells of a "challenge" question) supposed to apply the modulus at every multiplication, to keep the product in the range of `uint64_t`. Don't use signed. I see that the modulus is `1589540031`, which when squared can be held in 64 bits, so the product should always be in range.

Comment: I and @MOehm just told you how. But I haven't seen the question. if it is an online challenge, you go figure it yourself!

Comment: `k` and `j` could only become larger than 5000 if he was trying to calculate approx 1776! or higher, yet he says he's only trying with 100! or 200! and getting the issue. Tried his code as is and got the error once with inputs of 50, 500 - but could not repeat this with the same input again.  While your answer is correct, what he's seeing is more likely occurring due to use of un-allocated/un-initialized memory somewhere - probably caused by a logic error

Comment: NO. Its an online IDE so i can't say in what case it is showing this error.

Comment: @Tibrogargan what unallocated memory "somewhere"? That's the whole code. The question says up to 100000! and you don't get to see the test data for an online challenge.

Comment: @Weather Vane using Stack Overflow to solve the problem is not exactly challenging.  Neither is copying and pasting the code into a desktop IDE and trying with your own inputs.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I already said that. What is your point? Nobody has supplied any code.

Comment: @Weather Vane the OP supplied code.  The seg fault is reproducible by running his code.  If it was caused by the size of the inputs the error would be 100% reproducible with the same inputs.  Since you don't and it's not, it's not the size of the inputs causing the problem.

Comment: @Tibrogargan this answer addresses that - out of bounds array indexing, which has not been checked. I made a perfectly valid comment - that the solution cannot work anyway - not an answer.

Comment: @Weather Vane Not everything is about you.  Unless you are also Michael Walz, the comment was not directed at you.  This answer, while correct, is not the correct answer for this question.